# File watch in S3 and send the particular path to a program

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hive

I am new with S3 bucket processing.
 I run my hive scripts running in ec2-insctance and its results in the form of .csv files gets saved in their respective folders according to the script in S3. Now my requirement is that I have to have a file watch to see whenever a new .csv file is overwritten in every folders in S3 and send the full path of those .csv to my python program and call the program to run and save the output.csv in the same folder.It would be helpful if anyone can suggest some ways so that I could pick up and implement it.

Comment: AWS lambda is typically used for file watching

Answer (score 1):

1. you can use Spark Streaming to monitor a directory, kick off work when new entries are added. Needs to you run a spark cluster all the time.
2. you can set up S3 itself to send events through [S3 Event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) to their queue service or AWS lambda.

Option #2 is going to be the lowest cost and most reliable

Comment: Is it possible with Oozie Coordinator running in Ec2-instance? I am asking this because my python script reside in ec2-instance. And for S3 Event notification my ec2-instance doesnot have web server enabled. I am unable to proceed with only amazon documentation. Wanted some basic explanation rather than too complicated